# parameterized self hosted Integration Runtime in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have multiple IR for each client. I want to use one pipeline to copy data from client SAP table source to Blob.

How create parameterized Integration Runtime and pass it from data source level.

Comment: what exactly do you want to Parameterize ? SHIR cannot be parameterized, linked services using it can be

Comment: you can have multiple nodes though for single SHIR created

Answer (score 0):

I see [SAP table linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-table?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties) does not have an option to Parameterize connection properties using UI.

You can share the idea or feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c#) where similar asks are already made.

1. [Parameterize Intergration Runtime on Linked Service](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/a6daf2ce-7026-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)
2. [Parameterize the Integrated Runtime within the Linked Service](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/b9daf2ce-7026-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)

Meanwhile, you can download and install SHIR **on each different client** you have, [Install and register a self-hosted IR from Microsoft Download Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#install-and-register-a-self-hosted-ir-from-microsoft-download-center) using the same authentication keys to add them **as nodes to same SHIR**.

[image]

Comment: there is a limit for 4 nodes. Not useful for this purpose